# MVC Dropdown List using same source data with different selected data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched through what I could and if I've missed something forgive me.  However, I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:
Within my view, I need to produce a total of 9 lines with the following:
Type(as a dropdown), Action(as a dropdown) and the number of items(Textbox).

I'm working with the folowing model:

```
public partial class PM_REFERENCE_DATA_CHANGES
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string ACTION { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> QUANTITY { get; set; }
}
```

This is being used in MVC and will need to be able to pass back all 9 rows of data (Type, Action, Number) to be saved to the database.

This is my current code and while it produces the correct number lines, I'm having issues with it getting the right info on the right line:

```
            //Component are pulled from PM_REFERENCE_DATA_CHANGES
        //Get components of request
        var components = db.PM_REFERENCE_DATA_CHANGES.Where(r => r.ID == id).OrderBy(r => r.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE).ToList();

        //Get All Current Data Types
        var getTypes = db.PM_REFERENCE_DATA_TYPES.ToList();

        //Get the nubmer of components for the request
        var numberOfComponents = db.PM_REFERENCE_DATA_CHANGES.Where(r => r.ID == id).Count();

        //Create Action List
        List<SelectListItem> actions = new List<SelectListItem>();
        actions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "", Selected = true });
        actions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Add", Value = "ADD" });
        actions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Edit", Value = "EDIT" });
        actions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Delete", Value = "DELETE" });


        var componentArray = new List<PM_REFERENCE_DATA_CHANGES>();           

        if (components.Any())
        {
            //Loop through each row of components to build dropdown for Type, Action, Number
            foreach (var component in components)
            {

                //Create Type Dropdown
               // componentArray.Add(component);


                if (getTypes.Any())
                {
                    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
                    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" });
                    var item = new SelectListItem();
                    foreach (var type in getTypes)
                    {

                        if (component.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE.ToString().Equals(type.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE.ToString()))
                        {
                            item = new SelectListItem() { Text = type.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE.ToString(), Value = type.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE.ToString(), Selected = true };
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            item = new SelectListItem() { Text = type.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE.ToString(), Value = type.REFERENCE_DATA_TYPE.ToString() };
                        }

                        list.Add(item);
                    }

                    ViewBag.Types = list;
                    ViewData["Types"] = list;

                }

                componentArray.Add(component);

            }

            //for (var i = 1; i <= (9 - Convert.ToInt16(ViewBag.numberOfComponents)); i++)
            //{
            //    var component = new PM_REFERENCE_DATA_CHANGES();
            //    componentArray.Add(component);

            //}


        }


        ViewData["actions"] = actions;

        ViewBag.numberOfComponents = numberOfComponents;

        return PartialView(componentArray);
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong> @Html.DropDownList("Types", ViewData["Types"] as SelectList)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
            @Html.DropDownList("actions", ViewData["actions"] as SelectList,item.ACTION)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" style="width: 15px">
            @Html.TextBox("quantity", item.QUANTITY.ToString())
        </div>
    </div>
```

}

I know that I'm sorta close on this, but can't figure out how to get it do what I need.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot use the same name for the `SelectList` as the property your binding to. Rename it to (say) `ViewData["ActionList"] = actions;` and in the view use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.actions, ViewData["ActionList"] as SelectList)`. Then remove the `Selected=true` parameter from `SelectListItem` - its the value of property `actions` which determines what is selected (the `Selected` property is ignored when binding to a property of your model)

Comment: And do not create a `SelectListItem` with `Value="", Text=""` - use the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` to create the `optionLabel` - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.actions, ViewData["ActionList"] as SelectList), "Please select")`